# X is impossible for god, X is above god, if you eat X you will die, the rich need X , the poor have X, X is a 7 letter word?

Tags: riddle

X is impossible for god.

X is above god.

If you eat X you will die.

The rich need X.

The poor have X.

X is a 7 letter word.

What is X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 7 letter word should be...

> NOTHING

Because:

> Nothing is impossible for God, and nothing is above Him. You will die if you won't eat anything. The rich need nothing (because they can have everything)... and the poor... have nothing!